# <Half a bread>, <half a banana>, <half a bun>, <half a bar of chocolate>

Tags: word-usage, phrase-choice

Do you think it is correct to say

> **Half a loaf of bread**

> **Half a banana**

> **Half a bun**

> **Half a bar of chocolate**

instead of

> **A half loaf of bread**

> **A half banana**

> **A half bun**

> **A half bar of chocolate**

I feel like the use of "half a" is wrong with these things. What do you think? I think it is better to use "a half ..." because we are talking about a size instead of an amount.

Comment: Both of "half a bread" and "a half bread" are definitely wrong because we don't say "a bread": bread is a **mass** or **non-count** noun.

Comment: @stangdon Oh thanks. I forgot that. I should have said "a half loaf of bread" and "half a loaf of bread"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the items are obtained. If bread is sold in a package of one half loaf, then one would say "a half-loaf" of bread. If one cuts a loaf in twain, each is "half a loaf", or "half of a loaf."

In many markets, one may buy "a half watermelon," precut, or a whole melon, and slice "half a melon" at home.

However, a "bar" is not a unit of measure, unlike a "loaf" or a "melon," so "a half-bar of chocolate" is undefined.

Of course, a "[half Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_hold#Half_nelson)" hold is *never* "half a Nelson".

And "a half-cup of coffee" is not the same as [half a cup of coffee](https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/6359437/il_fullxfull.248703673.jpg).

Comment: Thanks. Why do you think it would be wrong to say "a half melon" or "a half loaf of bread" if we sliced it? And what exactly is the difference between *a half cup of coffee* and *half a cup of coffee*?

Comment: We count things in units, e.g. a loaf, a kg, a melon. If you served someone a "half-melon", that's correct usage. If the store has melons on display, precut, you'd also buy a "half-melon". If you must ask the clerk to slice a *whole* melon, you'd be more likely to say,"I'd like half a melon."